# How to access a python Flask app through R shiny?

Tags: python, html, r, flask, shiny

I am trying to connect a R Shiny app to a python Flask app, so that I can run my Shiny app on R studio connect and access my Flask app which in turn runs on localhost.

My initial attempt was a GET request from shiny to Flask to bring the html code onto my R site. This worked for displaying the html code, but sending elements back to the python side e.g. forms or pressed buttons are more complicated.

I was wondering whether there are other solutions that do not involve interference with the underlying network system such as IP forwarding?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone will ever run into a similar question. In the end I put the url generated by Flask in an R shiny iframe.